# JFoenix TabPane tab label colors

Tags: java, css, javafx, jfoenix

I'm working on my javafx project and i'm using JFoenix library. I found everything i need to edit TabPane look by CSS styling, bet one problem still remains - tabs header labels and bottom strip have some kind of blurry/shadow effects, and i can't find, how to fix this. This is my CSS now:

```
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
.tab{
    -fx-pref-width: 350;
    -fx-pref-height: 50;
}
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-selected-line {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary;
}
.jfx-tab-pane .tab .tab-label {
    -fx-font-weight: normal;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-primatytext;
    -fx-font-size: 16;
}
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-header-area .jfx-rippler{
    -jfx-rippler-fill :-fx-secondary;
}
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-selected-line{
    -fx-stroke : -fx-secondary;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Can you see it? Design of tabpane headers is not flat, like other UI, it have some kind of shadow/blurry effect. Can anyone tell me, where to look to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: That looks like an effect—likely a drop shadow. Assuming that's the "tab selected line", try adding `-fx-effect: null;`.

Comment: @Slaw doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to remove shadow of JFXTabPane:

```
.jfx-tab-pane .depth-container { -fx-effect: none; }
```